# password issue during build ios app with Phonegap

Tags: ios, phonegap

i want to build an ios app with phonegap and my p12 and cer files are located in 
github public link.
these files has no password and when i want to submit p12 file to phonegap it require a password.
is there any way to build ios app with these files on phonegap?

the files are located here : 
https://github.com/MohamadKh75/iOS_Development_Certificates

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/ios/ Also, you should NOT be sharing your cert file publicly. As per Apple "Do not share Apple Certificates outside of your organization."

Answer (score 0):

If there is no password in your p12 file, just press OK and it should work. Else you need to create a new certificate.

Comment: this is a public file for "local app store" in iran and i can not create a certificate. can you create one with password?

Comment: You need to purchase your apple developer account to create your certificate.